# Расстояние между точками

Tags: excel, координаты

Имеется два списка объектов (например, дома и остановки) с известными статичными координатами. Требуется для каждого дома определить ближайшую остановку. Расстояние между объектами я находил по формуле `=acos(sin(lat_a)*sin(lat_b)+cos(lat_a)*cos(lat_b)*cos(lon_a-lon_b)*R`, где `lat_a` и `lat_b` - широты объектов, `lon_a` и `lon_b` - долготы объектов, R - радиус Земли. В Excel это выглядит так:

```
     A  B   C         D        E         F
1   Дом Долгота Широта  Остановка  Долгота   Широта
2   №1  28,6806 57,6836 №1     48,7806     23,1881
3   №2  50,2042 23,1881 №2     53,7503     13,4358
4   №3  45,7356 72,2383         
5   №4  63,0503 13,4358
```

Используя формулу

```
=ACOS(SIN($С$2)*SIN(F2)+COS($C$2)*COS(F2)*COS($B$2-E2))*6371210
```

мы получаем по **2** значения для каждого дома (т.е. колво остановок).
Нахожу минимальное расстояние по ф-ле МИН. 
Затем, комбинацией функций `ИНДЕКС(...;ПОИСКПОЗ(МИН()...;...;0);1)` нахожу соответствующую остановку для конкретного дома. 
Можно ли как-нибудь организовать пересчет всех возможных вариантов в одной строке? То есть, составить формулу, выделяющую минимальное значение без построения колонки значений расстояний до каждой остановки?

Answer (score 1):

В Excel это выглядит немного не так: обычно диапазон таблицы и ссылки на таблицу совпадают :)

Задачу можно решить одной формулой. Для этого нужно задать диапазоны и объяснить табличному процессору, что делать с данными.

В Excel, кроме обычных формул, есть понятие "*формула массива*" - формула, ввод которой должен быть обязательно завершен нажатием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. 
Формулы массива не следует сравнивать со всеми формулами, обрабатывающими массивы данных. Это разные понятия.

Формула массива для строки 2 (получить **минимальное расстояние**):

```
=МИН(ACOS(SIN(C2)*SIN($F$2:$F$3)+COS(C2)*COS($F$2:$F$3)*COS(B2-$E$2:$E$3))*6371210)
```

Находясь в строке формул, нажать "комбинацию из трех пальцев", указанную ранее. Формула должна заключаться в фигурные скобки - **{}**. Все. Готово.

После ввода формулы ячейку можно копировать по строкам (протянуть вниз).

Формула находит количество значений, равное количеству ячеек в диапазоне, и показывает минимальное.

Получить **имя остановки**:

```
=ИНДЕКС($D$2:$D$3;ПОИСКПОЗ(МИН(ACOS(SIN(C2)*SIN($F$2:$F$3)+COS(C2)*COS($F$2:$F$3)*COS(B2-$E$2:$E$3))*6371210);ACOS(SIN(C2)*SIN($F$2:$F$3)+COS(C2)*COS($F$2:$F$3)*COS(B2-$E$2:$E$3))*6371210;))
```

Недостаток формул массива и обрабатывающих массивы данных: формулы тяжелы в обработке, производится много лишних вычислений, при большом количестве таких конструкций возможны торможения при вычислениях.

Формулы массива можно облегчить: добавить дополнительные столбцы (строки) с формулами, в которых будет производиться часть вычислений. Это намного упрощает вычисления.

Comment: Вы просто Гуру Экселя) Спасибо! Понятия не имел о "формулах массива". Может быть, подскажете мне **хороший самоучитель** по Exсel, дабы я освоил многие тонкости этого пакета?

Comment: Литературы много, но лучший самоучитель - практика.
 
Ссылки на ресурсы по изучению Excel и VBA:
http://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum.php?thread_id=10797

Учебники:
http://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum.php?thread_id=8763
http://www.excelworld.ru/index/bibl/0-5

Comment: Теперь проблема с тем, как возвратить **имя** остановки. ИНДЕКС(...;ПОИСКПОЗ(МИН()...;...;0);1) не работает.

Comment: Формулу добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для имени остановки формула должна быть такой (в авторском варианте - допущены опечатки).

```
=ИНДЕКС($D$2:$D$3;ПОИСКПОЗ(МИН(ACOS(SIN(C2)*SIN($F$2:$F$3)+COS(C2)*COS($F$2:$F$3)*COS(B2-$E$2:$E$3))*6371210);ACOS(SIN(C2)*SIN($F$2:$F$3)+COS(C2)*COS($F$2:$F$3)*COS(B2-$E$2:$E$3))*6371210;))
```